# Can this code cause memory leak with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

If I have companion object with hold context of others class like below.

```
class Sample01Activity: BaseActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun open(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, Sample02Activity::class.java)
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, null)
        }
    }

}
```

Did open(context) cause an memory leak in this code? And id it did, will it fixed with Weakreference like below.

```
class SampleActivity: BaseActivity() {

companion object {
    fun open(context: WeakReference(Context)) {
        context.get()?.let {
            val intent = Intent(it, Sample02Activity::class.java)
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(it, intent, null)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't store link to context anywhere so your first variant is completely safe

Comment: You can use activity context, instead of passing.  
Please specify your purpose of open method?

Comment: I want to use open method to open new Activity.

Comment: @AndreiTanana Then it mean that if I use context as parameter in companion object it will not make memory leak until I use some thing like val ctx = context in companion object right?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a context as an argument will not cause memory leak. The reference is released after the method returns.

If you assigned this context to companion object field, it could cause memory leak, but you never do that.